# Pen.Alignment is not working while drawing line

Tags: c#, winforms, graphic

I want to draw a thick line and a thin line. The thick line should be positioned inside of the theoretical line. So I set the pen alignment as below.

```
Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0), 1);
Pen greenPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0), 10);

greenPen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;

e.Graphics.DrawLine(greenPen, 10, 100, 100, 50);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 10, 100, 100, 50);
```

But the idea is not get worked. Any better idea to do the same ???

Comment: I guess `Inset` will only work properly with polygon. Did you read this part of the docs *A Pen that has its alignment set to Inset will yield unreliable results, sometimes drawing in the inset position and sometimes in the centered position. Also, an inset pen cannot be used to draw compound lines and cannot draw dashed lines with Triangle dash caps.* in [remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.alignment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: A rectangle or a circle have an "inside".  A simple line does not of course.  You'll have to offset the start/end points yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Hans Passant.

Answer (score 2):

[Pen.Alignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.alignment(v=vs.110).aspx) is partially implemented:

> This property determines how the Pen draws closed curves and polygons. The PenAlignment enumeration specifies five values; however, only two values—Center and Inset—will change the appearance of a drawn line. Center is the default value for this property and specifies that the width of the pen is centered on the outline of the curve or polygon. **A value of Inset for this property specifies that the width of the pen is inside the outline of the curve or polygon.** The other three values, Right, Left, and Outset, will result in a pen that is centered.

So, `Inset` will work only on polygons or curves (e.g. `Graphics.DrawRectangle`).

Comment: Did you read this "however, only two values—Center and Inset—will change the appearance of a drawn line" ? What does that mean then?

Comment: @Kaizen I'm afraid that they won't. Right, Left and Outset are equivalent to Center.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes :) `Inset` will change the appearance of a drawn line if this line is a part of curve or polygon.